# How to suspend UI / App Shell updates when manually removing and adding element to App Shell in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**My Question:**

In Xamarin.Forms 4.2+, can I suspend the App Shell in any way while I am manipulating it? Or can I suspend the whole UI layouting and rending for an instance?

**My Situation:**

I am creating an App with Xamarin.Forms where I use the new `Shell` Navigation. Cause I change the Flyout Menu during app runtime, I want to add and remove some of the `FlyoutItem` by code.

As an example, I have a `LoginPage` which I want to replace by a `UserProfilePage` in the App Menu (Flyout Menu). I always have an `AppInfoPage` in the menu.

Whenever I remove a `FlyoutItem`, Shell wants to display the next item. So when I remove the `LoginPage`, Shell displays `AppInfoPage` or at least calls the constructor and executes the overload of `OnAppearing` on the `AppInfoPage`. `OnAppearing` then does a lot of things to prepare the App info, which is not needed now cause the page will be `OnDisappearing` just a few ticks later.

Most UI frameworks have some function like this to avoid unneeded UI layouting and rendering. I tried setting `IsVisible = false`, `IsBusy = true` and calling `BatchBegin()`, but none of them helped me.

**Code Example:**

Check this simplified example, see the TODOs.

```
 private static void SyncAppShell()
 {
    try {
            // TODO Here I want to disable the automatic "navigation on menu modification"

            Current.Items.Add(CreateFlyoutItem($"{flyoutIdPrefix}-{nameof(LoginPage)}",
                resources[nameof(AppStrings.LoginPage)],
                NavigationConstants.LoginPage,
                new LoginPage()));

            Current.Items.Add(CreateFlyoutItem($"{flyoutIdPrefix}-{nameof(AppInfo)}",
                resources[nameof(AppStrings.AppInfo)],
                NavigationConstants.AppInfo,
                new AppInfo()));

            Current.Items.Remove(_staticReferenceToLogoutPage);
    } 
    finally 
    {
         // TODO Here I want to enable the automatic "navigation on menu modification"
    }
}

private static FlyoutItem CreateFlyoutItem(string id, string title, string route, ContentPage page, bool isEnabled = true)
{
    var flyoutItem = new FlyoutItem { Title = title, StyleId = id, IsEnabled = isEnabled };
    flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent { Route = route, Content = page });
    return flyoutItem;
}
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code with us to understand what you say?